# Finding a subspace which is in a direct sum with another subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I have a subspace $W$, which has a dimension of $3$. I am also familiar with the base of this subspace. Now, I need to find the subspace $U$ so that $W + U= M_{3x3}$ is a direct sum.
The approach that I was thinking of is to use the base of $W$ and extend it to the base of $M_{3x3}$. After I did that, the vectors from this extension would form the base of the unknown subspace $U$.

Hope I made the question clear enough. Just wondering if this approach is correct and would lead me to the correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes, though the vectors won't be $U$. I'm supposing you meant they will form a basis of $U$

Comment: @Michael yes, that is what I meant. They would form the basis of U, and therefore U would actually span over these vectors. Thanks

Comment: If $M=W\oplus U$, I recall the notation $U=M\ominus W$ for just this idea

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Inner products and orthogonal complements are irrelevant here. Direct sums need not be orthogonal.